# Is Realtime transcription feature is available in agent conference in twilio?

Tags: twilio, voice, twilio-conference

As per this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am74WU1zENA&t=727s), they shows that we can get real time transcriptions in agent conference, but I did not found any documentation on twilio docs,

basically, I want to add a bot in the conference, ( in agent conference, the bot will act like agent ), which get the real time call transcription, and based on that some operation will perform and return the response in audio format to that same conference. and real agent will supervise this conference and behaviour of the bot.

So is there anyone can guide me in this ? and for this realtime transcriptions in agent conference ?